# Time Node in Blender 2.81?

Tags: node-editor

I'm trying to make a Rorschach effect material. What I want to do is have the distortion on a Wave Texture node change over time. It seems to me that in earlier versions of Blender, there was a Time Node. Is there a way to do this in Blender now?

Comment: The time node is still there, but only in the compositor as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3):

This is the super-quick-and-dirty way to do it:

Simply double click the value of the distortion and type **#frame** into  instead of a number.

[image]

Then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This automagically creates a frame based driver.

The box will turn purple, indicating that it is being driven.

[image]

If you want to modify it, just double-click the value box and edit as desired.    Note that the hash disappears, in the driver editor as it is no longer required.

[image]

Yes, you can use simple mathematical expressions too e.g. **frame/10**

You can also right-click the purple box and select *Edit Driver* from the context menu.

Just remember if you want to make it a driver add the **#** symbol to the front.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert a keyframe directly on the node's distortion value. Just:

1. hover your mouse over it, click 'I' (it should turn yellow)
2. move to a later frame in your Timeline
3. change the distortion's value in the node
4. hover your mouse over the distortion socket and click 'I' again

If you hit play, that should result in the distortion value animating over time.

You can also achieve the same effect by controlling the distortion with a Driver tied to the current frame number:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/drivers/index.html